# Call collectionView(_ :layout:sizeForItemAt:) in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

I made the gallery using UICollectionView.

If you lower the screen, the image should continue to come out and stop at 20.

The code was constantly updated.
However, the function collectionView (_: layout: sizeForItemAt :) that sets the size of the cell did not work.
Therefore, only 20 images are displayed continuously.

On viewDidLoad()

```
if let layoutt = artCollectionView?.collectionViewLayout as? PinterestLayout
{
    layoutt.delegate = self
}
```

cell setting

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "HomeCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as? HomeCollectionViewCell,

    let arts = self.artList else { return HomeCollectionViewCell() }
    if arts.count > indexPath.row
    {
        let model = arts[indexPath.row]

        cell.imgView.sd_setImage(with: URLHelper.createEncodedURL(url: model.thumburl), completed: nil)
    }
    return cell
}
```

return cell size

```
extension HomeViewController : PinterestLayoutDelegate
{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, heightForPhotoAtIndexPath indexPath:IndexPath) -> CGFloat
    {
        return CGFloat(300.0)
    }
}
```

Currently, the function only executes once when the app starts. Do you know how to run that function every time I want?

Comment: Have you written **yourCollectionView.delegate = self** line in your code?

Comment: I added viewDidLoad () to the last line.

Comment: Please update the code for collectionView data source and delegate method implementation in question

Comment: do you call `collectionView.reloadData()` whenever you want it to update?

Comment: I added the code.
Yes I tried reloadData () inside the refresh function, but nothing happened.

Comment: Have you missed artCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout ?

Comment: I have not written anything other than viewDidLoad ().

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please follow the steps to install `PinterestLayout` in `UICollectionView` below.

Set `PinterestLayout` to your collection view.

```
let layout = PinterestLayout()
collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
```

Setup layout

```
layout.delegate = self
layout.cellPadding = 5
layout.numberOfColumns = 2
```

Implement methods of `PinterestLayoutDelegate`

```
extension CustomCollectionVC: PinterestLayoutDelegate {

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        heightForImageAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath,
                        withWidth: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        let image = images[indexPath.item]

        return image.height(forWidth: withWidth)
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        heightForAnnotationAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath,
                        withWidth: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        let textFont = UIFont(name: "Arial-ItalicMT", size: 11)!                
        return "Some text".heightForWidth(width: withWidth, font: textFont)
    }
}
```

When data is loaded invalidate layout as well as reload data on collection view.

```
collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
collectionView.reloadData()
```

**Observation:**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, heightForPhotoAtIndexPath indexPath:IndexPath) -> CGFloat
```

try this instead of above:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        heightForImageAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath,
                        withWidth: CGFloat) -> CGFloat
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`. 
You can read more about the protocol here:
[UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout)

**Example:**

```
extension viewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 50, height: 300)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the prepare() method of PinterestLayout class, you can see the below code

```
guard
    cache.isEmpty == true,
    let collectionView = collectionView
    else {
      return
}
```

When you reload the colectionView the cache is no longer empty, so it returns back without altering the layout.

So just remove the cache value when prepare is called. 
Add removeAll() before guard

```
cache.removeAll()
```