# Swift - The behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I am using from a `UICollectionView` and I need to delete some items from it, but when I delete like bellow:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CellItemSelectedLangShortTerm",
                                                  for: indexPath) as? HeadlineCollectionViewCellLangShortTerm
    cell?.lblSelectedLang.text = displayedSelectedLangFilterShortTerm[indexPath.row].listLanguageFilter
    cell?.btnDeleteLangSelected.tag = indexPath.row
    cell?.btnDeleteLangSelected.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleBtnDeleteLangSelected(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    return cell!
}
```

And:

```
@objc func handleBtnDeleteLangSelected(sender: UIButton){
    let selectedIndex = IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)
    CViewSelectedLang.deleteItems(at: [selectedIndex])
}
```

Get me bellow error:

```
The behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
2019-09-22 14:43:03.036600+0330 MyApp[7343:104811] the item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values, minus the content insets top and bottom values.
2019-09-22 14:43:03.036944+0330 MyApp[7343:104811] The relevant UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance is <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7f9cd7c09630>, and it is attached to <UICollectionView: 0x7f9cd8156a00; frame = (8 10; 300 35); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; autoresizesSubviews = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x6000002bb150>; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000cb0140>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {1210, 35}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}> collection view layout: <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7f9cd7c09630>.
2019-09-22 14:43:03.037075+0330 MyApp[7343:104811] Make a symbolic breakpoint at UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes to catch this in the debugger.
```

Comment: Did you implement `sizeForItemAt` to return an appropriate height for your cells?

Comment: @ Sweeper. No, I am using from multiplier for items in story board. What can I do?

Comment: Implement [`sizeForItemAt`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout/1617708-collectionview) then.

Comment: @ Sweeper. I am using from this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53004337/10211127 but get me same error.